# How to change path of syslog file from /var/log to /opt/log?

Tags: 14.04, syslog, rsyslog

I am using ubuntu 14.04. I have to change the path of syslog file from /var/log to /opt/log. I have changed the path in 50-default.conf file from /var/log to /opt/log. I have restarted the rsyslog service also still it is not working. So how can I change the path?

Comment: Why would you want to change a standard location for syslog to /opt?

Comment: That is one of my requirement that's why I have to change the location.

Comment: **Why** do you have a requirement to change the location to /opt? I suspect that others will ask the same question. You really shouldn't tamper with how the system is put together.

Comment: maybe if you tell your requirement, the community can give you a better solution. Never hesitate to share your problem, there are always smart solutions.

Comment: Thanks @luv.preet. Next time I will definitely tell my requirement with more information. I got the solution for the asked question. I will share the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I found the solution for this question.
It is as follows :

In 50-default.conf file. I added following lines at the end so that most of the messages get logged in the mylog.log file.

```
daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn   -/opt/log/mylog.log
```

After this in opt folder I created a log folder and changed the permission as  below:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/log

sudo chmod -c 777 /opt/log
```

Then in /opt/log folder I created a mylog.log file and here also I changed the permission as below:

```
sudo touch mylog.log

sudo chmod -c 777 mylog.log
```

And then I restarted the rsyslog service as follows :

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Hope this will be helpful for some people.

Thank You.